# Renamed image is not being saved to directory in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to taking an image uploaded in an HTML form, and then rename the image, and save it to the current directory. However, it seems that the image is never being saved to the directory.

HTML Form:

```
<form id="change_image_form" action="change_header_image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image: <input type='file' name='file' id='header_image' accept='image'/><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD IMAGE" onclick="index.php" name=upload>
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
define("HEADER_IMAGE_NAME", "header_image");

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    //Change name of file to the standard header name
    $extension = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = HEADER_IMAGE_NAME . "." . end($extension);

    //Move file to images directory
    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $newfilename)); 
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is the output of `var_dump`?

Comment: I assume you realise this will attempt to save EVERY uploaded file with the same name! Which at best will overwrite the previously uploaded file. Is that what you really want

Comment: @RiggsFolly, this is actually code to upload a header image for the web page. Once I get the upload working, I am going to add the code to delete the existing image

Comment: @u_mulder the output is `false` with the `name=upload` added to the form

Comment: Your `action="change_header_image.php"` does not match the script name `upload.php`

Comment: `<input type="submit"` does not need or want an `onclick` handler when inside a `<form>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed the `onclick` and it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're making two mistakes
1.your action="filename.php" should be the name of your php script
here you're using

```
action="change_header_image.php"
```

but you're file name is upload.php

2.in upload.php

```
if(issset($_POST['var'])
```

here var should be the name of your submit button
so edit
1.

```
form id="change_image_form" action="change_header_image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Edit 2.

```
<input type="submit" value="UPLOAD IMAGE" onclick="index.php" name=upload>
```

final code

```
<form id="upload.php" action="change_header_image.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image: <input type='file' name='file' id='header_image' accept='image'/><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name=upload value="UPLOAD IMAGE" onclick="index.php" name=upload>
</form>
```